# Getting "'int' object is not subscriptable" error while apply a method to a pandas data series

Tags: python, pandas, analytics

I have a stocks_df data frame that looks like that one in the picture. When I apply the lambda as in the picture it doesn't throw any errors.

However when I do

```
list = pandas.Series([1,2,3,4,5])

new_list = list.apply(lambda x: x/x[0])
```

It gives me "'int' object is not subscriptable" error. Is there any difference between the two? What am I doing wrong here?

[image: mentioned dataframe]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a series, apply operates element wise. To reference the first element of the series, you need to use list[0] instead of x[0]:

```
new_list = list.apply(lambda x: x/list[0])
```

For a DataFrame, apply by default operates column wise, that's why x/x[0] works.

To use the same syntax, you could use:

```
new_list = list.to_frame().apply(lambda x: x/x[0])
```

By the way, using built-in type name (list) as variable name is not a good idea.

Comment: @beebeckzzz because when you use apply on a df, x refers to the whole column, which is a Series, hence x[0] works.